# An example of wreath product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, wreath-product

I was analyzing the following example of wreath product of groups.

Let $\mathbb{Z}_2$ be the cyclic group of order two and $\mathbb{Z}$ be the usual additive group of integers. Consider the restricted wreath product $G:=\mathbb{Z}_2\wr \mathbb{Z}$ (where $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}_2$).

The problem I have is the following one: Is it possible to find a (strictly) ascending chain in $G$ of finitely generated non-Abelian subgroups?

I think this is not possible but I cannot show why. Any ideas?

Comment: By "$\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}_2$" do you mean that it acts on a countable number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ by shifting indices? Because there is no non-trivial action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Yes of course. I wrote it just because I do not remember what is the right orientation of the symbol $\int$.

Comment: Ok, good (you got it right). But it is indeed important to always mention what set one has the right-most group acting on (as this can be ambiguous in some cases).

Comment: I think you are correct that there is no such group, though I only have some general ideas to start. I think one can show that it is enough to consider subgroups obtained by picking some finite number of indices and some element from $\mathbb{Z}$. And then note that an infinite ascending chain of such subgroups would end up being a similar chain of subgroupf of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I was thinking of that too, but I couldn't get almost nothing of it. I was also thinking that one can perhaps reduce everything to subgroups isomorphic to $G$: in this way I think I can say something more using the theorem of Hall which asserts that metabelian, finitely generated subgroups satisfies the maximal condition on normal subgroups.

Comment: This is just to point out that there are two types of wreath product $A \wr B$, the restricted wreath product, where the base group is the direct product of copies of $A$ (i.e. only finitely many nontrivial components in each element), and the full wreath product, where the base group is the cartesian product of copies of $A$ (i.e. infinitely many nontrivial components allowed in elements). You have not made it clear which one your mean, although I am guessing that you mean the restricted wreath product.

Comment: I meant, as you thinked, the restricted wreath product. I have now correct the question.

Comment: I don't have much time so here are some thoughts. Show that any subgroup of $G$ that projects onto ${\mathbb Z}$ and has nontrivial intersection with the base group has finite index in $G$. So there can be no infinite ascending chain of subgroups projecting onto ${\mathbb Z}$. To prove the result, you need to generalize this to show that there is no such chain projecting onto any fixed nontrivial subgroup of $n{\mathbb Z}$ of ${\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff You're right, I was writing (and thinking) fast. Sorry.